# I would like to get an id(auto increment) after the post and post it into other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to post the id of the evenement table into the evenementontvanger.idEvent column. I tried to use the mysql_insert_id() but this doesnt work. ill tried it like this:

```
    <?php
    //include db configuration file
    include 'connection.php';
    function user_joined($user_werknemer,$user_project,$user_klant,$user_taak,$user_name,$user_desc, $user_start, $user_startdate, $user_starttime, $user_end, $user_enddate, $user_endtime, $user_color){

            $q = "INSERT INTO evenement (id,title,description,start,startdate,starttime,end,enddate,endtime,color) VALUES 
                ('','".$user_name."','".$user_desc."','".$user_start."','".$user_startdate."','".$user_starttime."','".$user_end."','".$user_enddate."','".$user_endtime."','".$user_color."') ";
            $qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak) VALUES ('".$user_werknemer."','".$user_project."','','".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."')";


        mysql_query($q);
        $id = mysql_insert_id();

$query = 'INSERT INTO evenementontvanger("idEvent") VALUES('.$id.')';
        mysql_query($qo);}


    if(isset($_POST['user_werknemer'],$_POST['user_project'],$_POST['user_klant'],$_POST['user_taak'],$_POST['user_name'],$_POST['user_desc'],$_POST['user_startdate'],$_POST['user_start'],$_POST['user_starttime'],$_POST['user_enddate'],$_POST['user_endtime'],$_POST['user_end'],$_POST['user_color'],$_POST['action'])){
            $user_werknemer=$_POST['user_werknemer'];
            $user_color=$_POST['user_color'];
            $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
            $user_desc=$_POST['user_desc'];
            $user_project=$_POST['user_project'];
            $user_klant=$_POST['user_klant'];
            $user_taak=$_POST['user_taak'];
            $user_start=$_POST['user_startdate']." ".$_POST['user_starttime'];
            $user_startdate=$_POST['user_startdate'];
            $user_starttime=$_POST['user_starttime'];
            $user_end=$_POST['user_enddate']." ".$_POST['user_endtime'];
            $user_enddate=$_POST['user_enddate'];
            $user_endtime=$_POST['user_endtime'];
            $action=$_POST['action'];
            if ($action=='joined'){
                user_joined( $user_werknemer, $user_project, $user_klant, $user_taak, $user_name, $user_desc, $user_start, $user_startdate, $user_starttime, $user_end, $user_enddate, $user_endtime, $user_color);
                }
        }
    /*if ( (isset($_POST["id"]) && strlen($_POST["id"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["id"]) <= 60) &&
        (isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["name"]) <= 50) &&
        (isset($_POST["age"]) && strlen($_POST["age"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["age"]) <= 40) ) 
    {   //check $_POST["name"] and $_POST["address"] and $_POST["city"] are not empty

        $id   = $_POST["id"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $age   = $_POST["age"];

        $q = "INSERT INTO tbltest ( id, name, age) VALUES 
                ('".$id."','".$name."','".$age."')";
        mysql_query($q); 

    }*/

    ?>
```

I also tried to work with last_insert_id. But this doesnt put the id in the idEvent too.

Comment: try INSERT INTO evenementontvanger(idEvent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following query,

```
$qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger
       (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak)
       VALUES 
       ('".$user_werknemer."', '".$user_project."',
        '', '".$user_klant."', '".$user_taak."')";
```

You are setting an empty string `''` from field `idEvent`.
You can directly use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in place of it, which is generated after executing the query defined for `$q`;

Like:

```
$qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger
       (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak)
       VALUES 
       ('".$user_werknemer."', '".$user_project."', 
        LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$user_klant."', '".$user_taak."')";
```

After executing `mysql_query($q);`,
Following statements are not necessary.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$query = 'INSERT INTO evenementontvanger("idEvent") VALUES('.$id.')';
```

Comment: Accepting Answers: timer?:P

Answer (score 1):

try to echo $id = mysql_insert_id();
if you have $id value or not or check with [empty()](http://www.php.net/empty)

try replace

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO evenementontvanger("idEvent") VALUES('.$id.')';
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger(idEvent) VALUES('".$id."')";
```

Comment: i checked if it was empty but somehow i dont get any echo: if (empty($id)) {
    echo '$id is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($id)) {
    echo '$id is set even though it is empty';
}